# invalid type int[int] for an array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, integer

Can you please help me to solve this problem?
Whenever I run it, it keeps giving me the error message.

> invalid type int[int] for an array subscript

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
void getdata (string [], int [][2]);

int main ()
{
int  temperature[12][2] = {0}, lowest, highest, averagelowest, averagehighest;
string month [12];
getdata(month, temperature);


return 0;
}

void getdata (string &b, int &a)
{
    ifstream inputFile;

inputFile.open("temperature.txt");
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            inputFile >> b[i] >> a[i][j] ;
        return ;
```

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite C?C++?C#? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main`, `month` and `temperature` are arrays. But your `getdata` function is taking references to a (single) `string` and `int`.

It could be that you meant `void getdata (string *b, int *a)`, which means they take pointers (which can point to either a single object, or an array of them).